# Forcing UTF-8 Encoding in a Command Prompt Invoked by Java? (Windows 10)

Tags: java, cmd, utf-8, command-prompt

I'm launching [Facebook / Duckling](https://github.com/facebook/duckling) via `Command Prompt` using the following code:

```
String dir = theDucklingDir;
String cmd = "stack exec duckling-example-exe -- -p " + port;
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start /min && " + cmd, null, new File(dir));
```

However, the data sent to Duckling was not being parsed due to the following exception:

```
A web handler threw an exception. Details:
TerminateSessionException user error (Text.Regex.PCRE.String died: (21,"invalid UTF-8 string"))
```

I noticed that if I manually execute the command: `CHCP 65001` in `Command Prompt` before executing:  `stack exec duckling-example-exe -- -p port` it solves the problem and the data is parsed as expected.

I tried replicating this when starting Duckling programmatically:

```
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start /min CHCP 65001 && " + cmd, null, new File(dir));
```

However, Duckling no longer starts when I add `CHCP 65001` before the main command.

How can I replicate launching Duckling with: `CHCP 65001`?

**UPDATE 1**:

In response to @Mofi request, I'm adding the output of commands `cdm /?` and `start /?` below:

```
cmd /?
Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter

CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
/S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K (see below)
/Q      Turns echo off
/D      Disable execution of AutoRun commands from registry (see below)
/A      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be ANSI
/U      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be
        Unicode
/T:fg   Sets the foreground/background colors (see COLOR /? for more info)
/E:ON   Enable command extensions (see below)
/E:OFF  Disable command extensions (see below)
/F:ON   Enable file and directory name completion characters (see below)
/F:OFF  Disable file and directory name completion characters (see below)
/V:ON   Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
        delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
        variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands variables
        at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR
        loop.
/V:OFF  Disable delayed environment expansion.

Note that multiple commands separated by the command separator '&&'
are accepted for string if surrounded by quotes.  Also, for compatibility
reasons, /X is the same as /E:ON, /Y is the same as /E:OFF and /R is the
same as /C.  Any other switches are ignored.



If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
used to process quote (") characters:

    1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
        on the command line are preserved:

        - no /S switch
        - exactly two quote characters
        - no special characters between the two quote characters,
          where special is one of: &<>()@^|
        - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
          two quote characters
        - the string between the two quote characters is the name
          of an executable file.

    2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
        a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
        remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
        any text after the last quote character.

If /D was NOT specified on the command line, then when CMD.EXE starts, it
looks for the following REG_SZ/REG_EXPAND_SZ registry variables, and if
either or both are present, they are executed first.

    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

```
start /?

START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
      [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
      [/NODE <NUMA node>] [/AFFINITY <hex affinity mask>] [/WAIT] [/B]
      [command/program] [parameters]

    "title"     Title to display in window title bar.
    path        Starting directory.
    B           Start application without creating a new window. The
                application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
                enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
                the application.
    I           The new environment will be the original environment passed
                to the cmd.exe and not the current environment.
    MIN         Start window minimized.
    MAX         Start window maximized.
    SEPARATE    Start 16-bit Windows program in separate memory space.
    SHARED      Start 16-bit Windows program in shared memory space.
    LOW         Start application in the IDLE priority class.
    NORMAL      Start application in the NORMAL priority class.
    HIGH        Start application in the HIGH priority class.
    REALTIME    Start application in the REALTIME priority class.
    ABOVENORMAL Start application in the ABOVENORMAL priority class.
    BELOWNORMAL Start application in the BELOWNORMAL priority class.
    NODE        Specifies the preferred Non-Uniform Memory Architecture (NUMA)
                node as a decimal integer.
    AFFINITY    Specifies the processor affinity mask as a hexadecimal number.
Press any key to continue . .
```

.

Comment: Please open a command prompt window and run `cmd /?`. The output usage help explains how the command line argument(s) after option `/C` or option `/K` are interpreted by the Windows Command Processor depending on multiple criteria which became very important to know on using operators like `&` and `&&`. Run next `start /?` for help on this internal command of `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Why do you use in Java `rt.exec` using on Windows the kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) to start `cmd.exe` to execute its internal command `start` which uses also `CreateProcess` to start `stack` if this executable or script file is found at all by `cmd.exe` as specified without file extension and without fully qualified path? I hope, you do not think the current directory on starting executables from within a Java coded program is always the directory containing the Java coded app.

Comment: That would be a completely wrong expectation. The current directory of a program is defined by the parent process on using `CreateProcess` to start the Java program with the function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory`. You could have more luck with `"cmd.exe /D /S /C \"%SystemRoot%\\System32\\chcp.com 65001 >nul & " + cmd + "\""`. Beside the awful variable name `cmd` which would be better named `command_line`, I think it would be better to use Java code to run directly `stack` with fully qualified file name in the environment expected by that program.

Comment: I recommend to read the documentation about the Java class [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) which gives a Java programmer more control over usage of `CreateProcess` than the class [Runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html). The character encoding for the input, output and error stream can be defined inside the Java program on using `ProcessBuilder` making it possible to run `stack` directly without usage of `cmd.exe` at all. The current directory can be also set with class `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: If you need examples, look on the Stack Overflow search results for [\[java\] ProcessBuilder UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+ProcessBuilder+UTF-8).

Comment: @Mofi Thanks for your reply. I am able to successfully execute: `String[] cmdAsArr = cmd.split(" "); ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(); pb.command(cmdAsArr); pb.directory(new File(dir)); Process p = pb.start();` But if I add encoding information ->  `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("chcp", "65001").inheritIO();` (before `pb.command(cmdAsArr);`) the process no longer starts..

Comment: In other words, I am unable to get `Process Builder` to launch the desired process/application **and** to preserve encoding information while doing so -- as I am able to do when opening up command prompt and entering the commands manually.. It seems I back to square one as this is the exact same result I was getting when using `rt.exec`..

Comment: You should not try to execute `%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com` to change the code page of the console. You should define the one, two or three streams inside your Java code and use the UTF-8 encoding for the stream(s) and run with `ProcessBuilder` the program `stack` using the UTF-8 stream(s) defined in your Java application. Please look on the answers found by the Stack Overflow search provided by me already in my previous comment.